# Multiple Database requests for login

Tags: php, function, authentication

I have three files that are relevant for this part of my login scenario:
/project/index.html
/project/api/user/login.php
/project/api/objects/user.php

The index.html has a simple login form in it, calling the ./api/user/login.php.
In this form I have a checkbox that is an option for the user in order to stay logged in or not.

If the user has selected this option, with every login, I would like to check if the credentials are correct (login function -> stmt1 in user.php) as well as to update the lastlogin (datetime), the identifier and securitytoken if the checkbox was set (login function -> stmt2 in user.php).

The user.php is included_once in the login.php that gets the values out of the index.html form and sends them to the login() function in the user.php.
Depending on the functions return value, the login.php decides if the login was successful or not.

The login itself (stmt1) works, but the update of lastlogin, identifier and securitytoken (stmt2) doesn't.

login.php

```
session_start();

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/user.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare user object
$user = new User($db);
// set ID property of user to be edited
$user->username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : die();
$user->password = base64_encode(isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : die());
$user->remember = isset($_GET['remember']) ? $_GET['remember'] : die();

$stmt1 = $user->login();
if($stmt1->rowCount() > 0){
    // get retrieved row
    $row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row1['uid'];

    // create array
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Login erfolgreich!",
        "uid" => $row1['uid'],
        "username" => $row1['username']
    );

    $stmt2 = $user->login();
    $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($row2);

    // create array
    $user_arr=array(
        "lastlogin" => $row2['lastlogin']
    );
}
else{
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Benutzername und/oder Passwort nicht korrekt!",
    );
}
// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($user_arr));
?>
```

user.php

```
function login(){
    // select all query
    $query1 = "SELECT
                `uid`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `created`, `lastlogin`
            FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " 
            WHERE
                username='".$this->username."' AND password='".$this->password."'";
    // prepare query statement
    $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare($query1);
    // execute query
    $stmt1->execute();
    return $stmt1;

    // set up the remain logged in function
    if(isset($this->remember)) {
        $identifier = random_string();
        $securitytoken = random_string();

        $remember = ",identifier='".$identifier."',securitytoken='".$securitytoken."'";

        setcookie("identifier",$identifier,time()+(3600*24*365)); //1 year valid
        setcookie("securitytoken",$securitytoken,time()+(3600*24*365)); //1 year valid 
    } else {
        $remember = "";
    }

    // update last login
    $query2 = "UPDATE
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                `lastlogin` = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'
                ".$remember."
            WHERE
                username='".$this->username."' AND password='".$this->password."'";
    // prepare query statement
    $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare($query2);
    // execute query
    $stmt2->execute();
    return $stmt2;
}
function random_string(){
    if(function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        $bytes = random_bytes(16);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes); 
    } else if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes); 
    } else if(function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $str = bin2hex($bytes); 
    } else {
        //secret key should have >12 random chars
        $str = md5(uniqid('SECRET KEY', true));
    }   
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  What is the runtime value of the query being executed?  Is it what you expect?  Are you able to execute that exact copied/pasted query manually?  It's also worth noting that your code is open to SQL injection, which is both a security hole and a common source of bugs, the latter of which could be exactly what's happening here.

Comment: The fail is, that it seems that only stmt1 (user.php) gets transferred to login.php.
The update just doesn't happen. 
In the index.php I do get an array with all the information of the stmt1. It is as if the stmt2 query gets somewhere ignored. 

Thank you for the SQL injection hint. I'm quite at the beginning of the implementation. I'm gonna harden the code so that SQL injection gets prevented.

Comment: "Just doesn't happen" and "gets somewhere ignored" implies that the code in question isn't executing at all.  You can confirm this with some debugging.  Even without the use of a formal debugger, you can add logging output throughout your code.  For example, imagine you have a generic function which writes a string to a log file.  Throughout your code you can call that function, writing useful pieces of information along the way.  So after the code runs you'd have a log of information about what happened.  Simple things like "Got to line 47" or the values of relevant variables.

Comment: What is `remember` in update query ??

Comment: @David: Sure, this is what I did as good as I can. This is why I can say that stmt2 doesn't get executed but I can't say why.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur: This is meant to be an optional SQL parameter. If the "remain logged in" checkbox is set, then make sure to set the identifier and securitytoken.

Comment: In `login()` function, you have written `return $stmt1;` comment this line.. When a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped. @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the user.php after return $stmt1;
The code is returned and the cookies are not set

I would do this... Check login... If true, save cookies with id and token
And then periodically check if token and id correspond... If so... Just UPDATE the last login time.

Note: your prepared statement is vulnerable!! Dont append the parameters with '.' use placeholders instead, and dont encode the password, is better to hash it... Then compare hashes